# Adding 1 million combinations of numbers to a file

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, memory-optimization

The code adds approximately 1,720,000 different combinations of numbers to a file, `some_other_file.txt`. The numbers range from 2 digits long to 16 digits long.

I add 500 numbers at a time to `some_file.txt` and upon hitting the 500th I move all the numbers to the end of `some_other_file.txt`.

My code works. But it takes ages to run and uses a lot of ram. How can I improve on them?

```py
while True:
    for u in range(1,501):
      with open('some_file.txt', "a") as file:
        for g in range(1,500):
          if (g % 100)==0:# speeds up the code by only running one out of 100 times
            os.system("clear")
            print("adding to file...")
            print ("sections loaded: "+str(u-1)+"/100")
            print("total loaded: "+str((g+((u-1)*500))*chunks)+"/"+str(length3))
            sleep(0.0000001)
          if ((g+((u-1)*500))*chunks)<=length3: # length3 is the length of the list I'm adding to file (1720000 long aprox) and chunks is how many times while True loop has run through
            file.write("\n"+update[((g-1)+((u-1)*500))*chunks])
          else:
            print("error")
            break
      with open('some_file.txt', "r") as file:
        l=file.read()
      with open('some_file.txt', "w") as file: # clears file
        file.write("")
      with open('some_other_file.txt', "a") as file:
        file.write("\n"+l)
      l=""
    if int((g+((u-1)*5))*chunks)>=int(length3): # chunks is how many times the while True loop has run through
      break
```

Comment: "I will update this post as I improve the code" please do not do that, that will make reviewing your code hard as it'll be forever shifting. Additionally upon getting an edit you are no longer allowed to edit the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We should remove the file information from the loops. We should interact with the files and the output outside the loop.

   **Note**: Code changed to follow a standard Python style

   ```py
   def generate_numbers(update, length):
       chunks = 1
       while True:
           for u in range(1, 501):
               for g in range(1, 500):
                   if chunks * (g + (u - 1) * 500) <= length3:
                       file.write("\n"+update[(g - 1 + (u - 1) * 500) * chunks])
                   else:
                       print("error")
                       break
           if int((g + (u - 1) * 5) * chunks) >= int(length3):
             break
           chunks += 1
   ```
2. We can see that `u` is always used as `u-1` so we should change the `range` to `range(500)`.
3. We should change `file.write` to `yield` and move the `"\n"+` outside the function.
4. Your control flow with `print("error")` is really odd. Let's run a quick whitebox test.

   ```py
   (u = 497, g = 1, length3 = 500, chunks = 1) # Part way through iterating
   > if chunks * (g + u   * 500) <= length3:
   >         1 * (1 + 497 * 500) <= 500
   >                      248501 <= 500
   > print("error")
   > break
   (u = 498)
   > if chunks * (g + u   * 500) <= length3:
   >         1 * (1 + 498 * 500) <= 500
   >                      249001 <= 500
   > print("error")
   > break
   (u = 499)
   > if chunks * (g + u   * 500) <= length3:
   >         1 * (1 + 499 * 500) <= 500
   >                      249501 <= 500
   > print("error")
   > break
   > if int((g +   u * 5) * chunks) >= int(500):
   > if int((1 + 499 * 5) *      1) >= int(500):
   > if                        2496 >= int(500):
   > break
   ```

   We should notice that there are 2 oddities here.

   - Your last if looks wrong. `(g+((u-1)*5))*chunks` should probably be `(g+((u-1)*500))*chunks`.
   - You should use a `try` and remove the `if` as `length3` looks like the bound of `update`.

```py
def generate_numbers(update):
    chunks = 1
    try:
        while True:
            for u in range(500):
                for g in range(1, 500):
                    yield update[(g + u * 500 - 1) * chunks]
            chunks += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

5. Since we've removed the file manipulation we can merge the loop to make `u` and `g` together.
   This is because they together make the range `500*500`.
6. We can change the `while True` to a for that calls `itertools.count`.

```py
import itertools

def generate_values(update):
    try:
        for chunks in itertools.count(1):
            for index in range(250000):
                yield update[index * chunks]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

---

Let's look at how you interact with the files.

```py
while True:
    for u in range(1,501):
        with open('some_file.txt', "a") as file:
            file.write(...)
        with open('some_file.txt', "r") as file:
            l=file.read()
        with open('some_file.txt', "w") as file:
            file.write("")
        with open('some_other_file.txt', "a") as file:
            file.write("\n"+l)
        l=""
```

It doesn't make sense to not just write to `some_other_file.txt` in append mode.

```py
with open('some_other_file.txt', "a") as file:
    for item in generate_values(update):
        file.write("\n" + item)
```

If you want to display the output then you can just use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). And you can use `enumerate` to build the index.

```py
def chunk_iter(it, amount):
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(it, amount))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk


with open('some_other_file.txt', "a") as file:
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunk_iter(generate_values(update), 100)):
        print("adding to file...")
        print(f"total loaded: {i * 100 + len(chunk)}/{len(update)}")
        for item in chunk:
            file.write("\n" + item)
```

Comment: I can't use intertools, I tried getting the code for the intertool functions off the official docs, but that wasn't working either (said num of arguments in generators weren't supported), what would be an alternative to that?

Comment: nvm, I'm going to code my own alternative to it.